# which hibernate class will support jpa CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

We sucessfully  implementedSpring , hibernate +jpa in our  application with Xa transcation.but  we trying to implement criteria  in our application we are facing one error  that ,

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()

So could you  tell which  implementation classes are using in hybernate  for  javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder interface
listed few  jar file we are using ,

> hibernate 3.3  ,  jpa 2.0
> spring-orm   3.0.2
> hibernate-entitymanager

#### Update:

I changed my  hibernate jar into( hibernate-core-3.6.0.CR2,hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.CR2  versions ) but  still same exception is coming ,

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder= this.getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();
```

In my config file:

```
<beans:bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory">
        <beans:ref bean="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- added by shiju  for getting atomoikas xa datasource-->
    <beans: property name="dataSource">
        <beans: ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </beans: property>
    <beans: property name="persistenceUnitName" value="payhub" />
    <beans: property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans: property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <beans: property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <beans: property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.target}" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans: property>
    <beans: property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
        <beans:value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder()Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder;...

Could you give any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Hibernate 3.3 doesn't implement JPA 2.  You'll need to upgrade to something more recent (e.g. 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder()

Maya,

getCriteriaBuilder() has to be called on an entityManager, not on entityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Hibernate 3.6.3 with JPA 2.0